# Differentiation under integral sign without DCT

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose $f: \Omega \times I \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable, where $\Omega$ is measurable and $I$ is an open interval. How do you show that if $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is uniformly continuous in $\Omega \times I$,  then $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Omega} f(x,t) dx = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) dx$?

You would surely have the left-hand side equal to $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\Omega} \frac{f(x,t+\epsilon)-f(x,t)}{\epsilon} dx$, so it suffices to show the limit commutes with the integral. If I could use the DCT, I'd just take any sequence $\epsilon_n$ going to $0$ and apply the theorem to the sequence $g_n = \frac{f(x,t+\epsilon_n)-f(x,t)}{\epsilon_n}$, which converges to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ (it shouldn't be difficult to bound the $g_n$).

Does uniform continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ imply uniform convergence of $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$? That's the actual issue. Is there a simple way to see this?

Comment: The answer to the last question is positive. Use the mean value theorem.

Comment: How so? Feel free to write an answer with more details if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, we have $$g_n=\frac{f(x,t+\epsilon_n)-f(x,t)}{\epsilon_n}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t+c_n),$$with $0<c_n<\epsilon_n$. If $\partial f/\partial t$ is uniformly continuous, it follows that RHS of the above converges uniformly to $\partial f/\partial t(x,t).$